# Get two elements from a sequence each time

Tags: clojure

Does clojure have a powerful 'loop' like common lisp.

for example:

get two elements from a sequence each time

Common Lisp:

```
(loop for (a b) on '(1 2 3 4) by #'cddr collect (cons a b))
```

how to do this in Clojure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By leveraging `for` and some destructuring you can achieve your specific example:

```
(for [[a b] (partition 2 [1 2 3 4])](use-a-and-b a b))
```

Comment: Do note that `for` is not a loop construct, but list comprehension, producing a lazy seq of results. Also, in contrast to Common LISP, it is hard to make it perform extremely well.

Comment: @Marko - do you have specific examples?

Comment: Don't understand -- examples of what exactly?

Comment: My point is not specific, but general. Lisp's `loop` is an execution-control construct, more akin to `doseq` or `loop` in Clojure. OP's example specifically uses `collect` to specify a `map`-like operation, this is just one way to use `loop`. In Clojure, things you typically use with `for` like lazy seqs, higher-order functions, auxiliary vectors that `partition` produces, etc. are all costly both in time and space.

Comment: @St3fan - thanks - my comment should have been 'examples of bad performance'. Hand-waving 'performs badly' or 'hard to make it perform extremely well' aren't that useful without specific use-cases. Performance isn't *always* the overriding concern, clojure trades cleanliness and simplicity  for raw performance in many places. The 'problem' then is that performance is easily quantifiable, where cleanliness/simplicity isn't, so evaluating the trade off can be difficult. I'd favour simplicity over efficiency and efficiency over performance unless and until I really knew I had a problem...

Comment: Just to level with you, @sw1nn, you are talking to a Clojure fan here (in fact, it's not far off to say I'm in love with it :). I am aware of everything you said and totally agree with it -- just when top-notch performance DOES begin to matter, Clojure shows it weaknesses. Try implementing a sort algorithm that performs within 50% of java.util.Arrays.sort.

Comment: Also, I was trying to contrast Clojure with Common LISP. That community's credo has always been "The Right Thing" -- in this context meaning "no-compromise performance achieved using perfectly beautiful constructs". How much they succeded in this is another topic.

Comment: @Marko - thanks for the comments. Actually I was hoping to learn more about (Common) LISP rather than disagree with you. ;-)

Comment: Positioning Clojure within the larger context of LISP is a very interesting topic for me. It is very difficult to find good discussions on this because few people have extensive experience with both, and are at the same time impartial enough to give relevant comments. I, for one, am only a spectator regarding Common LISP.

Answer (score 3):

There is [cl-loop](https://github.com/tayssir/cl-loop), which is a LOOP workalike, and there are also [clj-iter](https://github.com/nathell/clj-iter) and [clj-iterate](https://github.com/jpalmucci/clj-iterate), which are both based on the [*iterate* looping construct](http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) for Common Lisp.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure's multi-purpose looping construct is `for`. It doesn't have as many features as CL's `loop` built into it (especially not the side-effecting ones, since Clojure encourages functional purity), so many operations that you might otherwise do simply with `loop` itself are accomplished "around" `for`. For example, to sum the elements generated by `for`, you would put an `apply +` in front of it; to walk elements pairwise, you would (as sw1nn shows) use `partition 2` on the input sequence fed into `for`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with `loop`, `recur` and destructuring.

For example, if I wanted to group every two values together:

```
(loop [[a b & rest] [1 2 3 4 5 6]
       result []]
  (if (empty? rest)
    (conj result [a b])
    (recur rest (conj result [a b]))))
```

Ends up with a result of:

`=> [[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]]`

`a` and `b` are the first and second elements of the sequence respectively, and then `rest` is what is left over. We can then recur-sively go around until there is nothing left over in `rest` and we are done.

Comment: But that is already done by `(partition 2 [1 2 3 4 5 6])` giving: `((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))`.